# Modifying element in DefaultListModel not updating model

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jcheckbox, defaultlistmodel

I have a `JList` that is supported by a `DefaultListModel` and has a custom `CellRenderer`.

The `CellRenderer` is for adding support for `JCheckBox` in my `JList`.

When i try to modify the checked state for an element in the `DefaultListModel` it does not appear to update my `JList`. This happens when i try to use any of the three methods to get the element at a certain index: `DefaultListModel.elementAt(...)`, `DefaultListModel.get(...)` or `DefaultListModel.getElementAt(...)`.

**Why is my `JList` not getting the update?**

*The section of code below in my `JList` section that is commented out, will work. But, i do not like having to copy a new object into that position just to change the boolean.*

---

Here is my code, simplified for easy reading and understanding.

---

`JList` section

```
public AppsPanel() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    this.appsListModel = new DefaultListModel<AppListItem>();
    this.appsList = new JList<AppListItem>(this.appsListModel);
    this.appsList.setCellRenderer(new AppsListRenderer());
    this.appsList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
            int index = list.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());

            AppListItem appListItem = (AppListItem)list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
            appListItem.setSelected(!appListItem.isSelected());

            list.repaint(list.getCellBounds(index, index));
        }
    });
    this.appsScrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.appsList);
    this.add(this.appsScrollPane);
}
...
public void selectAllApps() {
//        for (int i = 0; i < this.appsListModel.size(); i++) {
//            this.appsListModel.set(i, new AppListItem(this.appsListModel.get(i).getApp(), true));
//        }
    for (int i = 0; i < this.appsListModel.size(); i++) {
        this.appsListModel.getElementAt(i).setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

---

`CellRenderer` section.

```
public class AppsListRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer<AppListItem> {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends AppListItem> list, AppListItem value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            this.setSelected(value.isSelected());
            if (value.getApp() != null) {
                this.setText(value.getApp().getAppName());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

---

`AppListItem` pojo

```
public class AppListItem {

    private App app;

    private boolean selected;

    public AppListItem(App app, boolean selected) {
        this.app = app;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public App getApp() {
        return app;
    }

    public void setApp(App app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

---

`App` pojo

```
public class App {

    private String appName;

    private String appPath;

    public App(String appName, String appPath) {
        this.appName = appName;
        this.appPath = appPath;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public String getAppPath() {
        return this.appPath;
    }

    public void setAppPath(String appPath) {
        this.appPath = appPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: please why JCheckBox as rendering JComponents inside non_editable JList

Comment: by default Boolean value stored in XxxXxxModel representing JCheckBox as rendering JComponents

Comment: Having a really hard time understanding your comments. =/

Comment: any logical reason for why is there `public class AppsListRenderer extends JCheckBox`

Comment: So each one of my rows that are rendered in my `JList` will contain a `JCheckBox`. I need each row to have a `JCheckBox`.

Comment: Your `selectAllApps()` does not trigger any event. Since you can’t invoke one of the `fire…` methods on the default model you should at least invoke `repaint` on the `JList` after the update. But I recommend implementing your own model; it’s not that hard.

Comment: @Holger: What `Model` should i extend to implement my own `Model`? Should i just extend the `DefaultListModel` or is there another one that would better solve my problem?

Comment: Extend `AbstractListModel`. You only need to implement two methods which is easy when delegating to a `List`, e.g. `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. And then add your own methods, of course.

Comment: @Holger: Ok, thanks. Can you post this as a solution to this issue. I will go and do this and if it solves my problem, i will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: What is issue? I dont see any issue. As you are updating model and calling repaint() on list, so it should work.

Comment: @Meraman the mouse listener does but `selectAllApps()` doesn’t.

Comment: So, after selectAllApps(), repaint() on list should be called to repaint list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `selectAllApps()` does not trigger any event. Since you can’t invoke one of the `fire…` methods on the default model you should at least invoke `repaint` on the `JList` after the update.

But I recommend implementing your own model; it’s not that hard.

```
public class MyListModel extends AbstractListModel<AppListItem> {

    ArrayList<AppListItem> list=new ArrayList<>();

    public void selectAllApps() {
        for(AppListItem i:list) i.setSelected(true);
        fireContentsChanged(this, 0, getSize()-1);
    }

    public int getSize() {
      return list.size();
    }

    public AppListItem getElementAt(int index) {
      return list.get(index);
    }

    // if you need such updates:
    public void add(int index, AppListItem item) {
      list.add(index, item);
      fireIntervalAdded(this, index, index);
    }

    public boolean remove(AppListItem i) {
      int index = list.indexOf(i);
      if(index<0) return false;
      remove(index);
      return true;
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
      list.remove(index);
      fireIntervalRemoved(this, index, index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method of AbstractListModel, at the point where you want the change to be applied to JList.

```
fireContentsChanged (model, changeStartIndex, changeEndIndex);
```

The changed elements are specified by the closed interval changeStartIndex, changeEndIndex-- the endpoints are included.

Example:
http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-674.html